# Disable mapping file (deob) upload on proguard build for Android Fabric/Crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

Android App using proguard:

> Crashlytics automatically uploads the mapping files for reach of your build variants.
>   https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html#gradle

We need to get rid off this warning since our bamboo build agent has no outside connection.

```
WARN - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the deobs file. 
Please check network connectivity and try again.
build   22-Jan-2018 15:20:18    
com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to cm.crashlytics.com:443
```

How can we disable this upload feature?

*Edit - clarification: We do not want to disable crashlytics for this build; in fact we need it.. We just want to disable the upload of the mapping file since we have no outside connection on this agent.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still looking to obfuscate your code but to not have the mapping file uploaded?

Comment: Hi, yes I want to obfuscate code and also use crashlytics but skip the mapping file upload (on the build agent).

Comment: Got it. There's no way to disable that upload when minifyEnabled is TRUE and without the mapping file you won't see deobfuscated stack traces. Are you uploading the mapping file on local builds then? If so, that message is just a warning and won't impact your builds.

Comment: Ok thx. I was just wondering since our build agent seems to have some trouble to successfully build (fails 4/5 times) and the 'Connection refused' is one of the first Exception in the logs. Therefore, my interest in getting rid of it and analyse the impact. (I try now some builds with disabled crashlytics but minify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable tasks by setting the `enabled`-flag in your top-level build.gradle file for specific tasks to `false`.

```
subprojects {
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        boolean isCrashlyticsTask = task.name.toLowerCase().contains("crashlytics")
        if (isCrashlyticsTask) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
          ext.enableCrashlytics = false
          ...
```

As in the [crashlytics documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds).

Comment: Hi, no I don't want to disable crashyltics alltogether just the upload of the mappings file.

Comment: but isn't that the same? or do you want to manually deobfuscate?

Comment: no I don't want to disable crashlytics, we need the error reporting; but I don't want to upload the mapping file (since the build runs on a build agent with no internet connection and will fail anyways)